# Google maps on 'how to find us' page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Does anyone know of any articles that will talk me through using google maps on a 'how to find us' page (asp .net c#):

http://www3.hants.gov.uk/education/professionalcentre/htlc-profcentre-howtofindus-2/htlc-profcentre-map.htm

http://www.raf.mod.uk/raflyneham/aboutus/findus.cfm

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using google maps, you can find the right location and click the small chain(link) icon in the top-left. It will give you the right html to paste in your source.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a link from google maps, you can e.g. use this library http://googlemap.codeplex.com/ which allows you to make geolocation lookups to.

Answer (score 0):

To add just one location [here are the instructions from Google Map](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-one.html)

Following links may help to find more ways to "Add Google Maps to your website":

- [Compare](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/compare.html)
- [Quick](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/quick.html)
- [Advanced](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/advanced.html)